# Is the '@' that precedes NSStrings actually an overloaded operator?

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring, operator-overloading, c-strings

When dealing with `NSString`s we always need to include de `@` at the beginning of the string.
For example:

`NSString *string = @"Hello, World!";`

`string` is an object of the class `NSString`.

Just crossed my mind that `@` could be and overloaded operator that transforms the C string into an object of the class `NSString`.

Is it so? Or is it just a reverie of my noob mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://guides.macrumors.com/Objective-C_Tutorial#The_.40_symbol):

> Using @ should make it easier to bolt an Objective-C compiler on to an
>   existing C compiler. Because the @ isn't valid in any context in C
>   except a string literal, the tokenizer (an early and simple step in
>   the compiler) could be modified to simply look for the @ character
>   outside of a string constant (the tokenizer understands string
>   literals, so it is in a position to distinguish this). When @ is
>   encountered the tokenizer would put the rest of the compiler in
>   "Objective-C mode." (The Objective-C parser would be responsible for
>   returning the compiler back to regular C mode when it detects the end
>   of the Objective-C code).

From the [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/index.html):

> The NSString class provides an object wrapper for strings that has all
>   of the advantages you would expect, including built-in memory
>   management for storing arbitrary-length strings, support for Unicode,
>   printf-style formatting utilities, and more. Because such strings are
>   used commonly though, Objective-C provides a shorthand notation for
>   creating NSString objects from constant values. To use this shorthand,
>   all you have to do is precede a normal, double-quoted string with the
>   @ symbol, as shown in the following examples:

```
NSString *myString = @"My String\n";
NSString *anotherString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", 1, @"String"];

// Create an Objective-C string from a C string
NSString *fromCString = [NSString stringWithCString:"A C string" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Your first sentence is a bit misleading. `@"Hello, World!"` creates a string literal at *compile time*. It does not call `stringWithUTF8String` at *runtime*.

Comment: @MartinR:- Got your point. Removed that! Actually what I meant was  when seen in front of a string literal, it makes an NSString rather than a 'char *' in C.

Comment: And what's the difference between a string literal and a `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)someString];`?

Comment: @gabriel_vincent, from a usage point of view they are the same, they are both instances of `NSString`. Are you specifically interested in memory management or something?

Comment: Thanks, @Wain! I was just curious.

Answer (score 5):

`@` is the indicator to the compiler that you are declaring some kind of literal. `NSString` (`@""`) isn't the only one, `NSDictionary` (`@{}`), `NSArray` (`@[]`) and `NSNumber` (`@1`, `@YES`) also have defined literal definitions.

Comment: So this is just a built-in characteristic of the language, right?

Comment: note: you can also use `@100`, `@NO`, `@YES` when using literal arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: @Bot, how did I forget `NSNumber` literals. Thanks